# Replacing meta-value on database

Tags: wordpress, replace, locking, edit

I need to migrate my wordpress site from local to online. I'm using custom post meta to upload files, so I need to change the string from "http://localhost/site" to "http://www.site.com/" but when I do it using some search and replace plugin, the value disapear. I think is because the new edit lock feature. How can I search and replace string on meta_value now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "WordPress Search and Replace Tool" - http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ This script allows to search/replace values even in serialized arrays.